# List of all servers and databases

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to write a stored procedure that lists the name of all the servers and their corresponding databases. I know that I can use osql/sqlcmd utility to list all the servers. But 'osql -L' doesnot support any other parameters with it like another -Q that can list all the databases. I would want to pull both servernames and their databases using the same query. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: What do you mean with list "all the servers"?, what servers are those?, linked servers on the one you want to run the SQL script?

Comment: @Lamak - The list of all servers on the network. Let's say I use the osql -L to pull all the servers on the network. I would like to write a sp with the list of all the servers and the list of all db's in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #servers(sname VARCHAR(255))
INSERT #servers (sname)
EXEC master..xp_CMDShell 'ISQL -L'
DELETE
FROM #servers
WHERE sname='Servers:'
OR sname IS NULL
SELECT LTRIM(sname)
FROM #servers
DROP TABLE #servers
```

Comment: I would like to list all the databases as well from the above query not just the servers.